# How can I optimize the performance of opening an Android fragment?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have created an 800 xml layout and a Fragment class, but opening a fragment with a button click takes too long.
Can anyone help me optimize the following code sample?

```
View lesson655 = (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtlesson655);

lesson655.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i;

            pager.setCurrentItem(0);

            for (i = 1; i <= 655; i++) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to go step by step through every Item you can do it this way:

```
View lesson655 = (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtlesson655);
lesson655.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(655);
        }
});
```

Comment: pager.setCurrentItem(x) is running only if x=0,1,2 not for the other integer values. It gives nullpoint exception if x>2.